# JavaScript não reconhece Dropdownlist

Tags: javascript

A cada mudança de dado do dropdownlist eu devo chamar uma função.
Porém não consigo faze-lo entrar na função.
Usei o Onchange mas não funciona.
Como fazer ?

Código asp:

```
<asp:DropDownList name="ddlFormaPagamento" ID="ddlFormaPagamento" runat="server"
Font-Bold="true" CssClass="newCombo" Width="340" AutoPostBack="True"onchange="javascript:VerificaIndisponibilidade();">
</asp:DropDownList>


//Função:
function VerificaIndisponibilidade() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ReservaTarifario.aspx/VerificaIndisponibilidade",
                data: JSON.stringify({ MsgErro: MsgErro }),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                dataType: "json",
                success: validar(Erro, "Indisponível"),
                failure: function () {
                    alert('');
                    fecharLoad();
                }
            });

         }
```

Answer (score 0):

infelizmente este `onchange` chama o método no `server-side`, caso queira fazer o `bind` do evento `change` no `JavaScript`, precisará fazer isto no `Code-Behind` ou direto no `JavaScript`.

**Code-Behind**

```
ddlFormaPagamento.Attributes["onChange"] = "VerificaIndisponibilidade();";
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("select[id$='ddlFormaPagamento']").on("change", VerificaIndisponibilidade);
```

Outro ponto, você setou o `AutoPostBack="True"` isto fará que o evento no lado do servidor seja acionado sempre que selecionar um valor, forçando o `PostBack` completo (caso não tenha um `UpdatePanel`).